# Solr is not indexing mysql database

Tags: mysql, solr, solrcloud

Hi Am trying to index mysql db to solr. But its only indexing id. I tried a lot. But no success. But I tried to index geo location in the same db for testing and its indexing all the cities successfully. I just what to know what am missing. This query contains some descriptions of the products like "Solr not returning results indexed from MySQL".

My db config

```
    <entity name="geo"  
    pk="id"
    query="select id, title from `inlive`"
    deltaImportQuery="select id, title from `inlive`"
    deltaQuery="select id, title from `inlive`"
    >
        <field column="id" name="id"/>
        <field column="title" name="title"/>
  </entity>
```

Schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<schema name="geo" version="1.5">
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
    <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true" />
</schema>
```

Result

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1506369405758"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "_version_":1579543508130201600},
      {
        "id":"2",
        "_version_":1579543508218281984}]
  }}
```

Debug

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 275
  },
  "initArgs": [
    "defaults",
    [
      "config",
      "data-config.xml"
    ]
  ],
  "command": "full-import",
  "mode": "debug",
  "documents": [
    {
      "id": [
        1
      ],
      "_version_": [
        1579544391043776500
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": [
        2
      ],
      "_version_": [
        1579544391046922200
      ]
    }
  ],
  "verbose-output": [
    "entity:geo",
    [
      "document#1",
      [
        "query",
        "select id, title from `inlive`",
        "time-taken",
        "0:0:0.10",
        null,
        "----------- row #1-------------",
        "id",
        1,
        "title",
        "test title",
        null,
        "---------------------------------------------"
      ],
      "document#2",
      [
        null,
        "----------- row #1-------------",
        "id",
        2,
        "title",
        "test title 2",
        null,
        "---------------------------------------------"
      ],
      "document#3",
      []
    ]
  ],
  "status": "idle",
  "importResponse": "",
  "statusMessages": {
    "Total Requests made to DataSource": "1",
    "Total Rows Fetched": "2",
    "Total Documents Processed": "2",
    "Total Documents Skipped": "0",
    "Full Dump Started": "2017-09-25 20:21:57",
    "": "Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 2 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
    "Committed": "2017-09-25 20:21:57",
    "Optimized": "2017-09-25 20:21:57",
    "Time taken": "0:0:0.255"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're missing `entity` end tags, and have you made sure to reload your configuration after changing it?

Comment: The entity close tag already present in this. Code editor missed the close tag. Any idea what am missing?

Comment: I found the issue. When I use
<field column="title" name="title_s"/> Its indexing. But I need to index it with title attibute.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the schema you've added in your question, but the default schema - have you reloaded the core or restarted Solr after changing the schema?

Comment: Yes. I added the schema. but its getting managed schema as primary. And showed warning in logging. Then only I can find the issues. I posted detailed answer for this. Now its working good.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the issue for this solr.

Am using solr 6.6
So I've to rename managed-schema to schema as per this tutorial in this link http://makble.com/how-to-index-mysql-data-in-solr. Also I made a test run with geo cities. By default it took managed schema as main schema it took my old test schema fields. Its not getting schema.xml.

So the solution is need to define schema.xml

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

Reference link : [Data-config.xml and mysql - I can load only "id" column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29492510/data-config-xml-and-mysql-i-can-load-only-id-column)

or rename managed-schema to schema.xml or delete managed-schema